# AHK help regarding RegExReplace

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I need assistance with RegExReplace in AHK.

I want my script to search text and keep only numbers after $ sign.

Right now I have:

```
F1::

 Clipboard = 

 SendInput, ^c

ClipWait

Variable := Clipboard

NewVar :=   RegExReplace(Variable,"[^.0-9]+", "{+}")

send % NewVar

return
```

For example if text is `"unit $400 unit 500 $400"` I get `400+500+400+`

What I would like to get is `"400+400+`"

I havent been able to figure out how to exclude numbers that dont have $ and I am not sure RegEx is the best thing to use here.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the final version, that does what I need. Thank you all for advise!!!

```
F1::        
Clipboard = 
 SendInput, ^c
ClipWait
Pos := 1
While Pos {
    Pos:=RegExMatch( Clipboard, "\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", M, Pos+StrLen(M1) )
    Match%A_Index% := M1 
    M2  := M2 Match%A_Index% "{+}"
}
Send % "=sum(" M2 
Send    {BS}{BS}){enter}
M2 :=
return
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NewVar :=   RegExReplace(Variable, "^.*?\s\$")
NewVar :=   RegExReplace(NewVar, "\s.*?\$", "+")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with `RegExReplace`, but I can suggest an example using the `RegExMatch` function.
Unfortunately, AutoHotkey doesn't support the `/g/` flag for the global searching, so you have to use a loop to search all values you need.

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input

F1::
    Clipboard = 
    SendInput, ^c
    ClipWait
    i := 1
    while pos := RegExMatch(Clipboard, "\$(\d+)", match, i)
    {
        i += pos
        sendinput % match1 "{+}"
    }
    ; sendinput {backspace} ; uncomment this line if you want the last PLUS character to be removed
return
```